# Nested Fragments bad practice?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, android-activity

I am creating my app. I am trying to follow all google's guidelines. There is a great part of UI - `Fragment`. It is really great thing that makes UI smoother and prettier.
Of course it is better to split my screen into separate logic portions of UI which can be later reused in another activity, layout whatever...
Fragments are more lightweight than `Activities`. Animation between fragments is smoother and looks better.

All that is great. What about using one `Activity` per app ?
According to the **Eric Burke** You have to use Fragment whenever you can do this. Here is the lecture - [Android App Anatomy](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Android-Design/).

Surely, using one `Activity` per full app can bring some benefits.
But of course there are some cons.

Let's consider simple app, it is not real app ,but just for example.

Here are three screens.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

It is not exactly the same UI as in my app, just for make it easier to understand my question.

There several ways we can follow to build such UI.

1. Each screen is single activity with it's own layout.
2. Each screen is again single activity but all portions are fragments, for instance on the first screen. It will be three fragments : ViewPager, Horizontal List and Custom View. Second screen will have only one `Recycler View` fragment and so on.
3. Use on activity for all screens. In this case we also have several ways.
   a) Use one container Fragment for whole screen and all widgets will be the part of one fragment layout.
   b) Use one container Fragment but with nested fragments.
   c) Use fragments without container and replace them all or some of them when we need to change UI, for example to change UI from first screen to the second we need to delete all fragments from the first screen and add one new fragment (list view), because we don't have the same parts of UI on these two screens.

All in all, I cannot decide for myself what and when to use, what is better according to the current guidelines, what can bring user better experience.

I am worrying about nested fragments, but if there was a bad practice, I think, google wouldn't add such feature into the framework. So may there is acceptable way.

I want to understand where it is better use Activity,Fragment or some mixture of them. There is no problem to write code for all this cases, but the main goal is to follow the best practices in building software architecture.

I will be really grateful for anyone who can help to understand this topic.
Thanks everyone who have read this to the end and those who can help me with this question.

Comment: Let's just put it that way. I have not seen any serious app with only one Activity, so take that with a bit of a reserve.

Comment: So what is best way in my case use three separate activities ?

Comment: It's really project specific, go with the path that will allow you the most abstraction and reusing stuff. Most commonly I'd say number two is okay.

Comment: I would say that if the logic needed to manage your fragments becomes complex, you probably should have used a seperate Activity. That is, having groups of fragments managed by an Activity. You can also use nesting, as you mention, to have a single 'top' fragment manage such a group. This way keeping the possibility of supporting multiple screen sizes (master/detail etc.).

Comment: "According to the Eric Burke You have to use Fragment whenever you can do this" -- given Mr. Burke's current employer, I suspect he does not use fragments much anymore. "I am worrying about nested fragments, but if there was a bad practice, I think, google wouldn't add such feature into the framework" -- you are absolutely welcome to your opinion. I would be willing to undergo a fair amount of torture before shipping an app with nested fragments. But, overall, this question is extremely broad and focused on soliciting opinions, which makes it not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you that this question is extremely broad, but I didn't find another place to ask and get answer from experienced developers. Maybe you can suggest or say what would you use in my case. 
Also maybe you can advice me where I can ask such type of questions, most of my questions  are about design patterns and best practices, code is not problem for me.

Comment: I went down the road of a single Activity once; it wasn't pretty.  You will run into so many weird issues that are confusing to debug.  I will never do that, nor nest fragments, ever again.